# Picking the first instance of a statictext in XCUITest

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, xcuitest

I have an app where there are a group of UIViews that are created, each with a label that contains dynamic StaticText.

Since this screen can have a random number of these static texts, I want my UI test to tap the first label that meets a specific string criteria.

So the idea that I'm tossing around would be somehow getting a list of all the labels, then tapping on the specific one I want.

Currently I have a few basic functions defined:

```
        let specificOrder = getTaskByIdx(1)

        if specificOrder?.waitForExistence(timeout: defaultTimeout) == false {
            app.swipeUp()
        }
        XCTAssertTrue(specificOrder?.waitForExistence(timeout: defaultTimeout) ?? false, "Could not find order.")

        specificOrder?.tap()
        specificOrder?.tap()
    }

    func getTaskByIdx(_ idx: Int) -> XCUIElement? {
        let tasks = getTasks()
        return getElementByIdx(tasks, idx: idx)
    }

    fileprivate func getTasks() -> [XCUIElement] {
        return app.collectionViews.children(matching: .cell).allElementsBoundByIndex
    }
```

This currently returns nil for `specificOrder`, and I'm kind of lost as to where. I'm telling it to build a list of all `tasks` as an Array, right?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this simple line instead of all the code you wrote

`app.collectionViews.cells.firstMatch.doubleTap()`

Read these articles to better know how to locate elements and interact with them
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement